Modify LINQ Query to Include Averages in Grid Display
I have the following LINQ query:
    var resultData = from audit in _context.audittable
                  join region in _context.Regions on audit.RegionCode equals region.RegionCode
                  where audit.SearchDate >= loieStartDate && audit.SearchDate <= loieEndDate
                  select new SearchCriteriaAuditDTO()
                  {
                      AuditId = audit.DbLagTestSearchCriteriaAuditId, //this primary key is hidden in the grid
                      SearchDate = audit.SearchDate.ToShortDateString(),//this is Date column just renamed on grid but the grid field is binded to this
                      OverAllAvgLagDays = audit.OverAllAvgLagDays,//binded to grid field just changed the name
                      RegionName = region.RegionName,//this is coming from a reference table which is a foreign key in audit table 
                      CategoryId = 
Convert.ToInt32(audit.CategoryId),//this returns id &is mapped to an enum of categories in backend&then mapped on grid based on id
                  };


This query gives the following table structure:

I want to modify this query to display averages in the grid as follows, where I calculate the average when the Region is "ALL" and the Category appears 3 times (not necessarily consecutively):

Can anyone help me modify the query to include this logic for calculating averages when the region is "ALL" and the category appears 3 times, regardless of whether they are consecutive or not?
There are 2tables (audit& region) in this query.Region is foreign key reference & Category is an enum .

Your posted LINQ query yields a different set of properties than is shown in your "This query gives the following table structure" image. (1) Please fix your post so that your data is consistent. (2) Post markdown tables, not images. (3) Define the criteria as to what values are included or excluded from the averages.

I have a potential answer, but cannot complete it until you resolve the inconsistencies in your question and add usable sample data (not images). Otherwise you can review and adapt the answers to a similar question here.

This question is similar to: LINQ to SQL version of GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you for ur response.i have added the required details in the queo &gone through the link u shared.the problem I have is when I do group by the data is sorted which I don't want.i don't need to sort my results rather have it as is &add additional rows of average (Region All'+3 same categories not necessarily consecutive)as shown in the second image .I hope I m making sense

Please post your data in a consumable format, such as a markdown table, that we can cut & paste. Images do not do not allow us to extract the values for testing. If you have trouble with markdown formatting, post as text and someone can help fix it.

I suggest you try making another query where you extract the data and aggregate it according to the average you need to calculate. Once you have your dataset, you can directly merge it with the first one you extracted.
The commands for averaging and aggregation are directly available with LINQ.
